# Socket.IO Admin UI - connected but data is not displayed

Tags: user-interface, websocket, socket.io, admin

I followed documentation for Socket.IO Admin UI (https://socket.io/docs/v4/admin-ui/) which is pretty simple, but I can't get it to work.

Let me tell you that my socket.io code works perfectly.

My code:

```
const { instrument } = require("@socket.io/admin-ui");

instrument(io, {
  auth: {
    type: "basic",
    username: "example",
    password: "$2a$10$Jisp23q0LsLDWTxS3p5MzOxf4Lu9y6r.example"
  }
});
```

The thing is that when I enter **server url** and hit connect (without username and password) it actually connects, but there is no data traffic. It's always on zero.

[image]

[image]

Why it ignores my credentials and why there is no traffic even though it says that it successfuly connected to socket.io server?

Answer (score 10):

I have found out what was the problem. Default namespace is "/admin" and had to change it to "/". :(

[image]